# How to Export Brynthum gantt chart data in to CSV format

Tags: javascript, excel, salesforce-lightning

How I can Export Brynthum gantt chart data in to CSV format using LWC Component in Salesforce

Is there is any way we can create export button on brynthum  gantt chart

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an LWC (Lightning Web Component) in Salesforce, you can export Bryntum Gantt chart data into CSV format. Here are the steps to follow:

Necessary for installation are libraries: PapaParse and Bryntum Gantt.

To showcase the Bryntum Gantt chart, let's whip up an LWC component. Our component must have both the necessary configuration and library for Bryntum Gantt.

To enable export capabilities, include a button or other UI component to activate it.

In your LWC component's JavaScript controller, make sure to include the export functionality.

How you can achieve this is exemplified below:

1:Necessary libraries must be installed:

The Bryntum Gantt library can be included by either downloading it from the website or via CDN.
Using npm or a CDN, install PapaParse to utilize its library.
Component LWC creation:
To create an LWC component:

2:Component LWC creation is step number two.

Using the Salesforce CLI or the Salesforce Developer Console, produce a component in LWC.
Include the container element for Bryntum's Gantt chart within the HTML file for the component.
Load the necessary data and configure the Bryntum Gantt chart in the JavaScript file.

3:Button: add export.

Add a UI element, such as a button, to prompt export use in the HTML component's file.
To handle the export action, assign an event handler to the button.

4:Implementing the export functionality is the next step. This feature enables users to export data from the system. It is a crucial requirement for any software program and has the potential to make or break the user experience. Therefore, it is an essential aspect that should be prioritized and completed as soon as possible. The implementation process requires careful planning and thorough testing to ensure that it works seamlessly. Moreover, the export functionality needs to be designed to cater to diverse user needs, making it more user-friendly and efficient.

Add an event handler for the export button in the JavaScript file of your LWC component.
Access the data of the Bryntum Gantt chart within the event handler.
Using the PapaParse library, transmute the Gantt chart data into CSV format.
Using the CSV data you've generated, it's possible to start a file download or produce a download link.
Implementation understanding can be aided by observing this code snippet sample:

```
// LWC Component JavaScript code
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import bryntumGantt from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/bryntumGantt';
import papaParse from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/papaParse';

export default class GanttChartComponent extends LightningElement {
    renderedCallback() {
        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, bryntumGantt),
            loadScript(this, papaParse)
        ])
        .then(() => {
            // Initialize the Bryntum Gantt chart here
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error loading scripts: ', error);
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error',
                    message: 'Failed to load scripts',
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
        });
    }

    handleExport() {
        // Get Gantt chart data
        const ganttData = this.getGanttData();

        // Convert data to CSV format using PapaParse
        const csvData = Papa.unparse(ganttData);

        // Create a download link and initiate file download
        const element = document.createElement('a');
        element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csvData));
        element.setAttribute('download', 'gantt_data.csv');
        element.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(element);
        element.click();
        document.body.removeChild(element);
    }

    getGanttData() {
        // Retrieve and format Gantt chart data here
    }
}
```

:)